# How to call REST API to external server from Jenkins when finish build

Tags: rest, jenkins, httprequest

I want to know how to call rest api to external server from jenkins when finish build.

I using [HTTP Request plug-in](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/), but there is no HTTP Request on 'Post-build action'

is it impossible?

[image: post-build options dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot execute additional plugins that are not listed using a `Free Style` Job. The best option for you, is to convert your `Free Style` Job to a `Declarative Pipeline`. You can read more about `Declarative Pipelines` from [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/). Once you move to a `Declarative Pipeline` you can invoke the `HTTP Request Plugin` like below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {
        // Install the Maven version configured as "M3" and add it to the path.
        maven "M3"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'

                // Run Maven on a Unix agent.
                sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean package"

            }

            post {
                success {
                   script {
                       echo "This will execute if the Job is Successful"
                       def response = httpRequest 'http://localhost:8080/jenkins/api/json?pretty=true'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you your answer. 

how to convert freestyle project to Declarative Pipeline ?

downloaded 'Declarative pipeline Migration Assistant', 'Declarative pipeline Migration Assistant API' , but there is no convert action ..

Comment: How to regist 'Jenkinsfile' ?

Comment: @seok0.2 You can refer to this article. https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipelines/declarative-pipeline-migration-assistant

Comment: Thank you. ! 

I simply use Convert to pipeline. thank your help.